# Any+has or have?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Let's say you are watching how burgers are made. Then, the t.v host cracked a joke by saying:

> Any foodies who **have** made it this far, look away now.

Or

> Any foodies who **has** made it this far, look away now.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "number" (singular or plural form) of the noun ('foodie' or 'foodies') determines the verb form of 'have', They must correspond in number.

> Any foodie *(singular)* who has *(singular)* made it this far, look away
> now.
>
> Any foodies *(plural)* who have *(plural)* made it this far, look away
> now.

Comment: Hmm, no, he said that ''any+foodies+have'' that's why I'm asking it why is that?

Comment: 'Foodies' is a plural noun, so we use the plural form of the verb ('have'), as I indicated in my answer. What is not clear?

Comment: When you use ''any'' then it should be followed by a singular noun right? Why is that 'the tv host'(native english) said **any foodies**. I am thinking he was grammatically incorrect... am I right?

Comment: "Any" is most often used with plural or non-count (mass) nouns. PluraI: Are there any doctors here? Are there any holes in your shoes? Non-count (mass): Is there any water in the jug? Is there any money in your pocket?  You would not say "I do not have any pen"; you would say "I do not have a pen". When the TV host said "any foodies" he was being grammatically correct.

Comment: I am wondering , cause it is basic grammar.